# Collect Shared Memory in Core dump

Tags: gdb, coredump

I have an application which crashed while accessing a shared memory.

```
typedef struct
{
...
} LinuxUserData;

LinuxUserData *ptrLinuxUserData;

fd = shm_open(shrSegName, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_EXCL, 0644);
ptrLinuxUserData = mmap(0, sizeof(LinuxUserData), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

But in the core the memory is inaccessible and it gives me error

```
(gdb) p *ptrLinuxUserData
Cannot access memory at address 0xeb80d050
```

This may be probably because core does not collect the shared memory details.
Also core man page mentions "Memory-mapped I/O pages such as frame buffer are never dumped, and virtual DSO pages are always dumped, regardless of the coredump_filter value."

**Is there any way through which shared memory or its details can be collected in core and accessed?**
or
What is the appropriate way to debug and root cause applications which cores at shared memory?